# How to find a partial directory path?

Tags: linux, find, coreutils

Suppose I don't know where my Django source is stored, but I know that it contains these directories in this way: `django/contrib/admin`.

How can I use the `find` command or any more appropriate coreutils command to find where this partial directory path (structure) is available?

Example output:

```
/home/me/python/extracted/django/contrib/admin/
/home/me/env/django/contrib/admin/
```

Comment: The **`locate`** command does this for you, assuming that its database is up to date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `-path` flag for such purpose

```
find /home/me  -path "*django/contrib/admin*"
```

Answer (score 1):

For people who don't have the `-path` option (ex: vanilla AIX install, and no GNU find installed), here is another (simple) solution:

```
find /home/me -print | grep "django/contrib/admin"
```